# Swift catching async function in different view

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I have an async function (geocodeAddressString) that gets called in the prepare for segue function. The problem is that this async function returns after the segue is executed. The async function below converts an address string into coordinates. I can't call this async function before this prepare function as the user address field can be edited by the user at any time. I've tried calling the async function when the save button is pressed and then coding the segue when the async function returns, but then the loading time between the button being pressed and the segue occurring is too long.

So my question is if there is any way that I can catch this async method in the new view? Then I could just replace some temporary coordinates with the actual returned values. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {    
    //convert address to coordinates
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(addressTxt.text!) { (placemarks, error) in
        guard
            let placemarks = placemarks,
            let location = placemarks.first?.location
            else {
                // handle no location found
                return
        }

            let tempCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (location.coordinate.latitude), longitude: (location.coordinate.longitude))
            self.donatedItem = DonatedItem(self.titleTxt.text!, self.itemImg.image!, self.donated, self.descTxt.text!, expirationDate, tempCoord, (user?.uid)!, (self.donatedItem?.itemID)!, self.addressTxt.text!, reserved: false, reservedBy: "NA")
            self.donatedItem?.updateItem()
    }

    switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {
    case "saveItem":

        homeViewController.isReturningSegue = true
        homeViewController.tempItem = self.donatedItem

    default:
        print("Undefined segue")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Post a notification to notify the new view. Or use closure. For example, this is notification.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "locationUpdated"), object: coordinate)
```

This is how to do this with closure.

```
typealias closure = (String) -> Void

class A: UIViewController {
    var coordinateUpdated: closure? // call this after coordinate updated

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let b = segue.destination as? B {
            coordinateUpdated = b.coordinateUpdated
        }
    }
}

class B: UIViewController {
    let coordinateUpdated: closure = { (coordinate: String) in
        // update here
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead pass on `addressTxt.text!` and then call the *async method* in the next view controller .

In the *current* view controller:

```
homeViewController.isReturningSegue = true
homeViewController.tempItem = self.donatedItem
homeViewController.address = self.addressTxt.text!
```

In the *next* view controller:

```
func viewWillAppear() {
    supper.viewWillAppear()
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(self.address) { ... }
}
```

If `geocodeAddressString` is taking too long (and affecting the UX) you could also put up a progress indicator. For instance, [MBProgressHUD](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MBProgressHUD) is a pretty common framework for such tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I prefer to avoid progress indicators when I can, but I'll keep that framework in mind for any situations where loading is unavoidable.